# Petersen graph is not a Cayley graph

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, cayley-graphs

How can I show that the Petersen graph is not a Cayley graph?

I don't know very much about Cayley graphs, I know that they are vertex-transitive, but so is the Petersen graph. It probably has to do with the group structure of $\Gamma$ in $Cay(\Gamma,S)$ (which is a group of order $10$, i.e., it is either the cyclic group $C_{10}$ or the dihedral group $D_{10}$). Then I am *guessing* we go for some sort of contradiction(?). My group theory is a bit rusty, I would very much appreciate someone showing me how to do this one!

Answer (score 10):

Let $ P\simeq Cay(G,S)$, then $|S|=3$ and $|G|=10$, then $G\simeq \mathbb{C_{10}}$ or $\mathbb{D_{10}}$, in both cases $G$ has cycle order 4, whereas $P$ has cycle of or 5.

Comment: Why does $|S|=3$?

Comment: P is a $3$-regular and $Cay(G,S)$ is $|S|$-regular.

Comment: Hi @mehranian Is there a direct way to show that there is a cycle of order 4? given one generator is idempotent and two more generators and 10 elements over all?

Comment: @mehranian Did you meant $D_5$ ?