# A Question about Cayley Graph

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, cayley-graphs

Petersen graph is this graph:

[image]

> Petersen graph can not be a Cayley graph.

How to prove that?

Can someone give a general method to judge a graph is or not a Cayley graph?

Comment: check this out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348779/petersen-graph-is-not-a-cayley-graph?rq=1

Comment: @hbm Why does $|S|=3$? I think $S=\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $a_1^2=1,a_2^2\ne 1$. Then every vertex has three neighborhoods and satisfies the question.

Comment: the graph is $|S|$-regular.

Comment: See here http://exwiki.org/mw/index.php?title=The_Petersen_graph_is_not_a_Cayley_graph